# Discord bot playing status

Tags: c#, discord.net

I have this peace of code

```
public class status : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{
  private DiscordSocketClient _client;
  public async Task StatusAsync()
  {
     var status = "eating doritos";
     await _client.SetGameAsync(string status, string streamUrl = null, ActivityType type = Playing);
  }
}
```

it's supposed to make my bot to "play" eating doritos, but everything here "string status, string streamUrl = null, ActivityType type = Playing" is in red
Some say "Invalid expression term" or "Syntax error, ',' expected
everything i want is fixed example

Comment: What you need is a basic c# tutorial. The Microsoft Docs is a great place to get started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
public class Help : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{
    [Command("test")]
    public async Task TestAsync()
    {
        await Context.Client.SetGameAsync("eating doritos");

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Head over to your **CommandHandler.cs** file. This is where you'll be editing for functions on startup. You're making this too complicated on yourself and I agree with @Camilo Terevinto that you should seek a basic tutorial. This will allow you a broader grasp on C# and Discord.Net. Best of luck and let me know if you have any more questions.

```
    public class status : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{
    private DiscordSocketClient _client;

public CommandHandler(IServiceProvider provider)
{
    bot = map.GetService<DiscordSocketClient>();
    bot.Ready += SetGame;
}
public async Task StatusAsync()
{
 await _client.SetGameAsync("eating doritos");
}
}
```